# Nested Datatable to nested list

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I'm getting dataset which contains datatables that can be 1,2 or 4.

I'm translating that into the list class which looks like below.

```
   public class test
    {
           public int id  { get; set; }
           public int name { get; set; }
           public List<test> LstTest {get;set;}
    }
```

For example, if i get 3 datatables into dataset, i'm suppose to create list of test class from first datatable,which contains another list(LstTest) which needs to populated from datatable 2 and again each object in this list contains LstTest which needs to be populated from datatable 3.

Can you please provide me solution for this. I'm able to do this statically,but the problem is this needs to be dynamic as number of datatables can be any e.g. 2,3,4 etc.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but should work, if i understood your requirement correctly:

```
public static List<test> GetTestLists(DataSet ds)
{
    var allLists = new Dictionary<int, List<test>>();

    // reverse loop necessary for efficient algorithm
    for (int i = ds.Tables.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        List<test> childList;
        bool hasChildren = allLists.TryGetValue(i + 1, out childList);
        var testList = new List<test>();
        DataTable tbl = ds.Tables[i];

        foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
        {
            var t = new test
            {
                id = row.Field<int>("Id"),
                name = row.Field<int>("name") // int for name ??
            };
            if (hasChildren)
                t.LstTest = childList;
            testList.Add(t);
        }
        allLists.Add(i, testList);
    }

    return allLists.TryGetValue(0, out List<test> parentList) ? parentList : null;
}
```

I guess `int name` should be `string name`. Also apply [.NET capitalization conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions).